# Copy matched regex to new file

Tags: regex, linux, sublimetext2

I want to copy regex matched text to a new file.

```
<SHOPITEM>([\s\S]*?)<YEAR>2015<\/YEAR>([\s\S]*?)<\/SHOPITEM>
```

`([\s\S]*?)` = any text, any line

This works (I am able to find) in Sublime editor, but how this regex looks for sed/grep (or any other Unix tool)?

Comment: Are you parsing XML with regex? If so expect problems. Do *The Right Thing™* and start using an XML library right away.

Comment: `grep` (Global regular expression print) will allow you to pretty much throw any `regex` you want at it. `sed` (Stream Editor Disk) uses it's [own](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) syntax for regex and most more complex regex patterns need to be formatted differently for `sed`

Comment: @MattGreen The problem here is multiline, which `grep` doesn't do (but its cousin `pcregrep` does) and for which `sed` requires some rather strange-looking syntax. But don't tell OP any of this, they shouldn't be using regex for this anyway.

Comment: @Biffen Yes, but this is a simple XML. I just need to filter out new items by <YEAR>. I don't see where can be a problem here (there is no need for complex processing).

Comment: @Adrian Can you swear on something you regard as holy that the nature of the input will *never* change? 'Cause it won't take more than some extra whitespace or an added attribute for your regex to fail. And don't even get me started on comments and CDATA blocks.

Comment: Hmm, you are right. Maybe there is a solution with XLST? Match all <SHOPITEM> where <YEAR> = 2015?

Comment: @Biffen Hmm, you are right. Maybe there is a solution with XLST? Match all <SHOPITEM> where <YEAR> = 2015? –  Adrian 19 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

Usually `sed` and `grep` are used to search on lines not on multiline mode as is it still possible under certain conditions.

I would advise to use Perl which should be installed on your computer:

```
perl -p -e 'undef $/;$_=<>;print $& if /<SHOPITEM>([\s\S]*?)<YEAR>2015<\/YEAR>([\s\S]*?)<\/SHOPITEM>/i;'
```

Be aware that this regex won't work if you have nested `<shopitem>` tags or even multiple occurences. Instead use a XML parser.

Also you can write a Program that parse your xml file and this time it will capture all the matches.

myparser.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
undef $/;
$_ = <>;
print while(/<(shopitem)>[\s\S]*<(year)>2015<\/\2>[\s\S]*<\/\1>/ig);
```

That you can execute:

```
$ chmod u+x myparser.pl
$ ./myparser.pl myfile.xml
```

Comment: I have many <shopitem> elements, maybe my original question is no-go here. I need to process the XML file to filter out <shopitem> elements where <YEAR> is 2015.

Comment: This perl solution looks nice, but for some reason the output is same as input (no process was made).

Comment: `chmod` is not needed to execute a script. Only read permission is enough if you call the interpreter (bash, python, php, etc.) I think this is more practical:
`$ perl myparser.pl myfile.xml`

Comment: @Adrian can you provide an example of your XML code ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the best scripter, but I think this should work:

```
grep "<SHOPITEM>" infile | grep "<YEAR>2015"  | sed -e "s/<[^>]*>//g" | sed "s/2015/ /g" > outfile
```

Edit: I didn't match the regex, instead I got SHOPITEMs with YEAR 2015 tag and removed all the unwanted parts.

Edit: I'd do it this way, but I'm not sure it's the most elegant solution.